msvc cannot initialize rvalue reference from value
MSVC (std:c++14) is complaining when initializing an rvalue reference using non-static data member of a prvalue (returned by function call).
The code is as follows (or see Compiler Explorer):
struct R {};

struct A {
    R r;
    R getR() { return r; }
};

A getA() { return {}; };

int main() {
    A &&aa = A();            // okay
    A &&aaa = getA();        // okay
    R &&rr = getA().r;       // should be okay, but not
}

Both GCC and Clang seem okay, and MSVC with /std:c++20 is okay as well. Is this a compliance issue of MSVC or am I misunderstanding something?

You just need to kindly ask MSVC to be compliant with permissive minus: /permissive-: https://godbolt.org/z/1rK5dTjnc
The flag is enabled by default for C++20

Ah I see, thanks! Interesting that it's permissive by default.

@Andrew - It used to be permissive as the only choice for a long time.  So when you ask it to use an old standard, it also enables all the "features", as they used to be in "the bad old days".
